# NotificationChannel: listen for changes in the categories (sound changed, vibration enabled)

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-channel

I have a `RingtonePreference` and a Vibration `Preference` and I'm trying to adapt the pre-26 behavior to newer versions of Android.

Since it's not possible to update the sound in a `NotificationChannel` once it's created, I'm planning to delete the old channel and create a new one every time the user changes the sound or vibration preferences.
This is fine, except for the case when the user changes this directly from the `NotificationChannel` thingy settings. I would have to reflect those changes in the app Settings too.

Is there a way to listen for changes in the NotificationChannel so I can update the app Settings too?